# How can I use Neovim regex to make a separated selection (of two characters not following one another)?

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm attempting to replace all strings in a text file surrounded by single quotes and ending with an @ first followed by any number and then any mix of any other letter(s) or #(s) like these:

```
'package@1.1.k'
'otherpackage@14'
'anotherpackage@7.8'
```

and I wish to select *only* the single quotes and remove them like so:

```
export MYVAR="/dir/'package@1.1.k':$MYVAR"
```

to:

```
export MYVAR="/dir/package@1.1.k:$MYVAR"
```

in the entire file. I figured out a way to remove the proceeding single quote and preceding single quote in two separate commands (using vim's `zs` and `ze`, similar to positive and negative lookarounds):

```
:%s/'.*@.[0-9]*.*\zs'//g 
:%s/\zs'\ze.*@.[0-9]*.*//g
```

However, I am curious about doing it in a single operation as I want to learn more about using Neovim, and apply the answer to future operations.

*I am actually using Neovim, if that comes with any additional features related to this.*

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm sorry that was a typo. I meant followed by. 

Thank you, I fixed my question. However, I know the regex for that match, my primary question is about selecting two characters (or possibly in another case – strings), that are separated by other characters and/or whitespace without selecting what's in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
%s/'\([^@'0-9]*@[0-9][^']*\)'/\1/g
```

**Details**:

- `'` - a single quote
- `\(` - start of a capturing group

  - `[^@'0-9]*` - zero or more chars other than `@`, `'` and digits
  - `@` - a `@` char
  - `[0-9]` - a digit
  - `[^']*` - zero or more chars other than a `'` char
- `\)'`  - end of the capturing group.

The replacement is `\1`, the Group 1 backreference/placeholder.

Comment: *Tysm!!:) For anyone confused about* **how to insert into / replace both of the selections instead of removing them –** replace the outer `'`  `'` in the %s/ command with the characters you wish to replace. Put what you wish to replace the first selection with in the replacement field after the `/` before the `\1` backreference, and what to replace the second selection with after, like so ........ :                          

`:%s/'\([^@'0-9]*@[0-9][^']*\)'/PREPEND\1APPEND`

Answer (score 3):

You can replace matches of the following regular expression with the content of capture group 1.

```
'([^@']*@\d[^@']*)'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iRck9o/1)

I'm not familiar with Vim's regex engine, but I understand it is quite robust. Considering that the regular expression I have suggested is nothing fancy (just making use of a capture group) I'm confident it should work in Vim.

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
'           # match a single quote
(           # begin capture group 1
  [^@']*    # match zero or more characters other than '@' and a single-quote
  @\d       # match '@' followed by a digit ofollowed by zero or more characters
            # other than '@' and a single-quote
  [^@']*    # match zero or more characters other than '@' and a single-quote
)           # end capture group 1
'           # match a single quote
```

I've assumed that there can be at most one '@' between asterisks, but if more that one is permitted (if, for example, `'a@11@22*'` is to be converted to `a@11@22*`) change the regular expression to

```
'([^']*@\d[^']*)'
```